# How to deduce class type from method type in C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, traits

In templates as shown below, I would like the call `Run(&Base::foo)` succeed without the need to name the Base type twice (as is done in the compiling `Run<Base>(&Base::foo)` call). Can I have that? Possibly without adding a ton of [Boost](http://boost.org) headers?

With the provided code, I get an error of:

```
prog.cpp:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘Run(bool (Base::*)())’
```

(you can fiddle with the snippet at http://ideone.com/8NZkq):

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  bool foo() { return true; }
};

Base* x;

template<typename T>
struct Traits {
  typedef bool (T::*BoolMethodPtr)();
};

template<typename T>
void Run(typename Traits<T>::BoolMethodPtr check) {
  T* y = dynamic_cast<T*>(x);
  std::cout << (y->*check)();
}

int main() {
  Base y;
  x = &y;
  Run<Base>(&Base::foo);
  Run(&Base::foo); // why error?
}
```

Comment: you know, compilers don't automagically work like you want them to...

Comment: What's with the hard questions on SO this morning?  Usually its a bunch of "how do you format a hex number" or "what is a const method."  This morning I actually have to think. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `T` in `Traits<T>::BoolMethodPtr` is in a non-deduced context, so the compiler will not deduce automatically from the call what type T should be.
This is because there could be code like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Traits {
  typedef bool (T::*BoolMethodPtr)();
};

template<>
struct Traits<int> {
  typedef bool (Base::*BoolMethodPtr)();
};

Run(&Base::foo); /* What should T be deduced to? Base and int are both equally possible */
```

If you can do without the `Traits<T>` class, you can write `Run` as:

```
template<class Class>
void Run(bool (Class::*check)()) {
  Class* y = dynamic_cast<Class*>(x);
  std::cout << (y->*check)();
}
```

In this context, `Class` can be deduced to mean `Base`

Comment: d'oh! Your answer is better than mine.

Comment: Sure I can do without! Aargh, so you're saying it's doable, and I've overcomplicated; LOL, life's funny :) Thanks a lot for the solution; regarding the explanation, it looks like I'll have to approach it some other day, after a good night's sleep ;) kudos to everybody on that thread, you'll get your +1s, all answers are very interesting, each one brings a part of the puzzle out

Answer (score 5):

To pick apart a type, any type, use partial specialization. There is no function template partial specialization, so you'll need to directly parameterize the function on its argument type and retrieve the class type inside.

```
template< typename T >
struct get_host_class; // most types are not ptmfs: don't implement this

template< typename C >
struct get_host_class< bool (C::*)() > { // implement partial specialization
     typedef C host;
     typedef void sfinae; // disallow function for non ptmf arguments
};

template< typename T >
typename get_host_class<T>::sfinae Run( T check) {
    typedef T BoolMethodPtr; // or something
    typedef typename get_host_class< T >::host host;
}
```

Comment: Um... not a template expert here, so could you please elaborate on what 'sfinae' and 'ptmf' expand to? for me at least, that would make it easier to read :)

Comment: @aka: sfinae = Substitution Failure Is Not An Error, a trick for (among other things) emulating partial specialization in functions. ptmf = Pointer To Member Function, the kind of type that is causing you, and many others, grief.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Although in my personal case (fairly simple), I'd prefer to Ctrl-C & Ctrl-V or #define for clarity, this could still be useful in some more complicated ones. +1 also for a bunch of quite interesting metaprogramming techniques in the snippet :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a non deduced context.

> $14.8.2.5/5- "The non-deduced contexts
>   are: — The nested-name-specifier of a
>   type that was specified using a
>   qualified-id."

I think this is the quote that applies in this case. But some template gods need to ratify my understanding.

Comment: Have you memorized the Standard or what? `:)`

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler tries to match a template argument, it only considers the primary class type.  In other words, when it encounters the expression:

```
Run(&Base::foo);
```

...and it's trying to figure out the template parameter for `Run`, it only considers the type of `foo` itself, and doesn't consider whatever class `foo` is a part of.

EDIT:

And the type of `foo` is `bool(Base::*)(void)`, but what you want the compiler to find is just `Base`

Comment: The compiler can actuallu deduct Class from bool(Class::*)() in this context, see Bart's reply.