# iterators in c++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have a little problem and I'm working on it for several hours but can't find a solution. Hope you will help me.

Here is my class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T> class Array{
private:
    size_t size;
    T *newArray;

public:
    class Iterator:public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, T>{
        T *p;
        public:
            Iterator(T*x):p(x){}
            T& operator*() {return *p;}

    };

    Array (size_t size = 10): size(size), newArray(new T[size]){};
    Iterator begin(){return (Iterator(newArray));}

    T printBegin(typename Array<T>::Iterator it){ return *it;}

    template <typename E>
    T printBegin(typename Array<E>::Iterator it){ return (T)*it;}

};
```

And here is Main:

```cpp
using namespace std;

int main(){

    Array<int> x;
    Array<int> y;
    cout << y.printBegin(x.begin()); // prints 0 OK

    Array<double> p;
    // cout << p.printBegin(x.begin());

    return 0;
}
```

The first `cout` works fine but the line that is commented gives this : `error: no matching function for call to ‘Array<double>::printBegin(Array<int>::Iterator)’`

I don't understand because the last line in my Array class matches (normally) for this function call

Comment: I found [this answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6569653/2507444) that describes issues with trying to automatically deduce the a template function argument using a nested class (such as your `Array<E>::Iterator`). Also note that you can explicitly specify the template argument and it will work - `cout << p.printBegin<int>(x.begin());`.

Comment: It seems, that E cannot be deduced automatically. Try it this way:
`cout << p.printBegin<int>(x.begin());`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the template argument deduction not working here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268504/why-is-the-template-argument-deduction-not-working-here)

Comment: Your class doesn't make any sense whatsoever. Why should the `Array` class know how to print itself? Why should it be able to print other arrays other than its own? Why are you not using `std::array` or `std::vector` together with `std::copy`/`std::back_inserter` or a simple `for` loop to print the elements out on `std::cout`? Do you have a Java background?

Comment: [OT]: You should avoid C-cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to deduce the `E` in `Array<E>::Iterator` from `x.begin()` that is an `Array<int>::Iterator`. But that is simply not possible.

Your best option is probably to write:

```
template <typename IT>
T printBegin(IT it){ return (T)*it;}
```

<s>If, for any reason, you need to use the `E` type, then it is better to add a nested typedef:</s>

```
class Iterator:public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, T>{
    public:
        typename T array_member_type;
        //...
};
```

And then:

```
template <typename IT>
T printBegin(IT it){
    typedef typename IT::array_member_type E;
    return (T)*it;
}
```

**Wait!** Your iterator derives from `std::iterator` so the typedef already exists. No need to redefine:

```
template <typename IT>
T printBegin(IT it){
    typedef typename IT::value_type E;
    return (T)*it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very similar to another question about template deduction.

The compiler cannot deduct the type `E` from `Array<E>::Iterator`. Why should it be able to? Two different types `E` could share the same iterator type.

What you are really saying to the compiler is:

"Is there a type "E" for which `Array<E>::Iterator` is this type?"